# GraphQL Java : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, graphql

I am testing the APIs after hosting the application on DigitalOcean and I got this Error :

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH2xs.png)

The query and my Service File looks like that :

[Repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOMQi.png)

[Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g71qp.png)

When I requested in postman like this. Getting Internal Server Error :

[Postman Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOSZD.png)

GraphQL Config :

[Company Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/um0jq.png)

[Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFfXw.png)

Comment: Please use proper code tags to include the code not links to images.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are repeating the query: I don't understand why the first line in your Postman test. Try like this:

```
query {
  getEsgScoresData(name: $name) {
    date
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added my GraphQL schema :) Thank's for your help

Comment: After repeating the query as I suggested, do you still get the same error?

Comment: Hi Julio, well I have some values in the database in Mongo with null values which blocks the API